# Implementation of long double in c++

Tags: c++

Recently I was doing some research about types in c++ and I have couple questions about `long double`. For instance I have some number `long double x = -48.12e4`, then how accurate should I translate 0.12 to hex or bin (I prefer to use hex , easer to read). In the scheme of implementation I have 1 extra bit and I have no idea about its role -

```
//scheme 
1bit    15bit   1bit   63bit 
sign    e        1       m
```

For example lets take number that I have written before.

```
1)translate decimal to hex 
-48.12 = -3.1E (are 2 digits after decimal enough?)

2)normalization 
0011.0001 1110  * 10^0 =  001.1 0001 1110 * 10^1

3)calculation of "e"
16 383 + 4 + 1 = 16 388 = 4004(hex) = 0100 0000 0000 0100

4)collecting everything together
1    0100 0000 0000 0100   1    1000 1111 0000 0..0
sign|        e           |bit|      mantisa 
What is that 1 bit for?
5)reverse order
0..000  0011 1100 0110  0000 0010  1010 0000
```

Have I done everything right?

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ ; a `long double` is different on x86-64 and on ARM64 ...

Comment: Why don't you just print out the value using [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and the `"%La"` format specifier? At least it should tell you what the hex-float value is on your current platform.

Comment: what sense of seeing result with out understanding how it is done?

Comment: Then you could easily see if you're correct, or work your way backward?

Comment: `-48.12e4` is `-481200`, which is `FFFFFFFFFFF8A850` in 2's complement hex.

Comment: i'm getting results that are not even close to mine therefore i'm asking if everything is right with my version

Comment: @mch: Yes, but `long double` doesn't use 2's complement, that's only applicable to integral types.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) (emphasis mine) :

> long double - extended precision floating point type. Does **not**
>   necessarily map to types mandated by IEEE-754. Usually 80-bit x87
>   floating point type on x86 and x86-64 architectures.

You assume a specific layout of `long double` that is by no means guaranteed by the standard but may vary from compiler to compiler and depending on the target architecture.

Comment: That quotation isn’t particularly helpful. It’s true that `long double` doesn’t necessarily map to types mandated by IEEE-754, but neither do `double` or `float`. The C++ standard doesn’t require any particular representation for any floating-point type so long as the range requirements are met.

Comment: @PeteBecker might be that it isnt particular helpful. tbh I didnt really understand the question. However, unless there is a better answer I will just leave it here

Comment: Keep the answer. It’s right, although a bit thin; it’s just the quotation that’s a bit misleading. At the moment you’ve got one upvote; that’s mine.

Comment: @PeteBecker ah ok, so you are "complaining" about the quote mentioning specifically only `long double` when similar is true for almost any other type?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you're doing decimal math. That's logical for humans, but not how computers work.

In particular, `-48.12e4` is specified as sign,mantissa,exponent, and that's also how the C++ implementation of `long double` works, but the implicit base for the exponent differs. `e4` signifies a power of 10, but `long double` uses base-2 (or base-16, or another binary base).

The consequence is that the compiler cannot just convert exponents. 10^3 is *approximately* 2^10, but not even close enough for `float` let along `long double`.

So, the proper solution is a lot harder. Perhaps the easiest solution is to calculate `long double(4812)` and `long double(1e2)`, and to multiply those. That way, you only need to implement the conversion of integers to `long double` and the conversion of powers of 10 to `long double`.

The conversion of small positive powers of 10 to `long double` is also easy, reuse the integer code. For large even positive powers, use squaring. For negative powers of 10, use the fact that `pow(10,n)=1.0/pow(10,-n)`.

To get an idea how real compilers do it (which is a fair bit more efficient), look at open-source implementations of `strtod()`.